# Uevent as a simple notification from kernel to userspace

Tags: linux, events, kernel

There is a kernel driver sending events to an application. This is done using a procfs file that blocks on read until a new event must be reported. The application reads this file and gets blocked until there is new information.
This approach works but doesn't look nice to me.

Now I found `uevent` as a notification mechanism that seems to be used for this purpose.
But it seems to do much more than just that. I read about hotplugging devices, registration of devices and so on and I need to register a kobject to do that. All this makes me unsure if uevent is too excessive for simply sending a short message from one driver to a dedicated userspace application.

Is a uevent the appropriate means for what I want to do or is it too much overhead and I should use something more simple?

By the way I am trying to find a good example how to use uevent as a notification only. Is there something understandyble that doesn't focus on all the mentioned other features?

Comment: Use threads or sub processing in your application.

Comment: @0andriy how exactly is this meant? Stay with proc file and have a thread read this file?

Comment: Yes. The main thread in application won't be blocked.

Comment: @0andriy This is correct I'm doing this in my code in this moment. I ask this question because I'm looking for a more elegant means to get notified of kernel activities.

Comment: Look at the libaudit. Though I feel it is utilizing the same mechanism, I.e. netlink.